# Import HTML content from EXCEL

Tags: c#, excel, ado.net, oledbconnection

I'm using OleDbConnection to get data from excel file and filling dataset/datatable. It loads just plain text from the cells, but few of the columns has html content like bold, italic words.

Sample code:

```
string strConn = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=Test_Import_ReqTemplate.xls;Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\"";
                DataSet _dsReqTemplateFromExcel = new DataSet();
                _connForExcel = new OleDbConnection(strConn);
                _connForExcel.Open();
                _dtReqTemplateFromExcel = _connForExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);                    
                _daReqTemplateFromExcel = new OleDbDataAdapter(@"SELECT * FROM [" + _dtReqTemplateFromExcel.Rows[0]["table_name"].ToString() + "]", _connForExcel);
                _daReqTemplateFromExcel.Fill(_dsReqTemplateFromExcel);
```

How to get the data with html styles and format.

Comment: what method are you using to read the data from the your excel sheet? can you show some code?

Comment: @user1666620 edited and added code snippet.

Comment: Try adding "xml" to the extended properties:  "Excel 12.0 xml"

Comment: Yeah tried the same, but results same, it is giving plain text only. @CarlProthman. Any ohter why where we can get import data from EXCEL?

Comment: Sure there lots of ways to get data from Excel.In addition to Microsoft ACE OLEDB 12.0, there is: .NET Framework Data Provider for OLE DB, Microsoft Jet OLE DB 4.0, Microsoft Excel 2007 ODBC Driver, OpenXML, and Excel.Application.  Make sure to check out each Excel connection string here:  https://www.connectionstrings.com/excel